# Is MemberInfo (and its implementations) considered singleton?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am generating a dictionary of mappings from an unrelated source to a target object using expression tree logic and a fluent API, using `MemberInfo` to identify the member to be written to.

I would like to ensure that if duplicate mappings are made (for whatever reason) I can either fail or warn at runtime. Is it safe to assume that `MemberInfo` (and its implementations) are unique, and singletons to the derived member? That is, would it be viable to use as a key in a collection?

For arguments sake, I am only targeting publicly writable properties at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are singletons (for those who viewed my previous answer, there was a hiccup involving `MemberInfo[]` vs `MemberInfo`).

You can prove this:

```
void Main()
{
    MemberInfo a = typeof(a).GetMember("b")[0];
    MemberInfo b = typeof(a).GetMember("b")[0];

    Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b));
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class a
{
    public int b;
}
```

Prints `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the revision. One would assume that equality would be invoked on the concrete assuming they were of the same type. As an extension of the original question, would using PropertyInfo have any benefit over any other unique identifier? I originally asked this question due to MemberInfo already being available in the calling scope.

Comment: @DanielPark I'm not sure I understand what you mean by having any benefit? Which other unique identifiers do you have in mind? Using `PropertyInfo` works fine; assuming you only care about properties

Comment: I was thinking a fully qualified name, or maybe some identifier that I am unaware of. Don't mind me though, classic case of trying to find a solution to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @DanielPark The only problem I can see with using `*Info` types is that if you were to define `b` as a subclass of `a` - getting the member info of `a.prop` will be different from `b.prop`, though they refer to the same definition.

Comment: the types are sealed with no intent of subclassing at this stage, so this will do nicely.